# Run n tasks sequentially based on previous task

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to create a DAG, which would run n+1 tasks, where n will be based on the output of the previous task (task1)

task1 looks the following way:

```
def get_n_of_commits(ti):
    n_commits=random.randint(1,10)
    ti.xcom_push(key="n_commits", value=n_commits)
 
task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'get_n_commits',
        python_callable =get_n_of_commits
    )
```

Then I need to use this key="n_commits" to create n_commits tasks following task1, but I can't find a way how to access `ti` outside of the task instance.

This is the result I'm trying to get achieved with a static number of tasks (hardcoding n_commits):

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='mimic_activity_v13',
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2023,4, 19),
    schedule_interval='@daily'
) as dag:

    chain_operators=[]
    n_commits=5

    for n in range(n_commits):
        task1=BashOperator(
            task_id = f'task_{n}_out_of_{n_commits}',
            bash_command = 'echo success message'
        )
        chain_operators.append(task1)

    for i, val in enumerate(chain_operators[:-1]):
        val.set_downstream(chain_operators[i+1])
```

2 problems/questions I have:

1. how to access ti.n_commits outside of the task instance?
2. Is there any better way how to execute n tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Airflow 2.3+ you can use Dynamic Task Mapping and the Taskflow API.

The Taskflow API is a great suite of decorators that handles the logic of passing xcom values more easily between tasks. Dynamic Task Mapping is a great way to create tasks at Runtime

```py
import logging

# import TaskFlow decorators
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import datetime

@task
def first_task()->list:
    import random
    n = random.randint(2, 10)
    my_list = list(range(1, n+1))
    return my_list


@task
def say_hello(i:int)->None:
    logging.info(f"hello world {i}!")


@dag(dag_id="dtm_dag_test",
     schedule_interval=None,
     start_date=datetime(2023,1,1))
def my_dag():
    # the .expand() method will create a separate taskInstance for each item in the list
    return say_hello.expand(i=first_task())

dag=my_dag()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Although it's not working for me and I get this error: 

airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to _PythonDecoratedOperator (task_id: say_hello__1). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'retry_interval': datetime.timedelta(seconds=120)}

Do you know how to fix it? 

P.s. this is the same error I'm getting when I tried to solve my issue with expand method myself
P.p.s I'm using Airflow 2.5.3

Comment: Removed retry_interval from args and it worked! 
P.s. still puzzling to me why retry_interval would influence execution of PythonOperator

Comment: Can you try using `retry_delay` instead of `retry_interval`?

 Here is a link to the partial kwargs https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L209